# Weird stepper motor behaviour on RAMPS in arduino

Tags: arduino-mega, motor, stepper

Following this tutorial:

http://www.instructables.com/id/Complete-newbie-step-by-step-3D-printer-with-all-p/?ALLSTEPS

I connected DVD stepper motor to RAMPS 1.4 on arduino with Marlin software with this settings:

```c
 //#define DEFAULT_AXIS_STEPS_PER_UNIT   {80,80,4000,500}  // default steps per unit for Ultimaker

 #define DEFAULT_AXIS_STEPS_PER_UNIT {215.12,215.12,8034.69,196.52}

 // #define DEFAULT_MAX_FEEDRATE          {300, 300, 5, 25}    // (mm/sec)

 #define DEFAULT_MAX_FEEDRATE {100, 100, 2, 25}

 // #define DEFAULT_MAX_ACCELERATION      {3000,3000,100,10000}    // X, Y, Z, E maximum start speed for accelerated moves. E default values are good for Skeinforge 40+, for older versions raise them a lot.

 #define DEFAULT_MAX_ACCELERATION {200,200,50,5000}


 #define DEFAULT_ACCELERATION          100    // X, Y, Z and E acceleration in mm/s^2 for printing moves

 #define DEFAULT_RETRACT_ACCELERATION  100    // E acceleration in mm/s^2 for retracts

 #define DEFAULT_TRAVEL_ACCELERATION   100    // X, Y, Z acceleration in mm/s^2 for travel (non printing) moves
```

I put a [video at vid.me](https://vid.me/vd6Q) (hopefully with sound) showing stepper behaviour when I press +1mm,-1mm,-1mm,-1mm,-1mm,-1mm,-1mm,+1mm,+1mm,+1mm,+1mm  on Pronterface software.

Comment: What did you expect/want to happen, and how is that different from what actually happened? Do know know how to detect which 4 wires from RAMPS go to which 4 wires on the stepper motor? What happens when you use a slower acceleration?

Answer (score 1):

The video you show shows movement of far more than 1mm.  This indicates that the steps per unit is far different than you are configuring the Marlin software for.  With a +/-1mm and 212 steps per mm, there should have been 212 steps sent to your stepper.

Recalculate your steps/mm values and slow down the feed rate to get something reliable.

For experimenting, in Pronterface, set the feedrate of 10mm/sec (600mm/min) or 1mm/sec (60mm/min) to slow things down so you can hear or count the steps with your ear, then choose smaller steps, like +0.1mm and see if you get the planned displacement.  If, at a really slow speed, you don't get the corresponding movement, then your steps/mm need adjustment to match your system.

Eyeballing it, I'd say the called-for 1mm or 212 steps is moving the stage about 10mm, so you would need numbers more like this for the x and y axes:

```
#define DEFAULT_AXIS_STEPS_PER_UNIT {21 ,21 ,8034.69,196.52}
```